# What is wrong with my insert BST implementation in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement BST, but the head value of my tree returns None every time. I've tried to look up other implementations in Python but they usually just declare a root and pass it in outside of the class itself instead of having the head self contained in the class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            for elem in nodes:
                self.insert(self.head, elem)
        print(self.head) #prints out None every time

    def insert(self, currentNode, data):
        if(currentNode == None):
            currentNode = Node(data)
        if(data != currentNode.data):
            if(data < currentNode.data): 
                if(currentNode.left is None): currentNode.left = Node(data)
                else: self.insert(currentNode.left, data)
            elif(data > currentNode.data): 
                if(currentNode.right is None): currrentNode.right = Node(data)
                else: self.insert(currentNode.right, data)

    def inOrder(self, data=None, visitedHead=False):
        if not visitedHead:
            self.inOrder(self.head.left, True)
            print(self.head)
            self.inOrder(self.head.right, True)
        elif(data == None): return
        else:
            self.inOrder(data.left, True)
            print(data)
            self.inOrder(data.right, True)

treeTime = Tree([1, 80, 3, 0])
```

Comment: Where in your code do you actually assign anything to `self.head`? This `currentNode = Node(data)` only creates a local variable, it doesn't actually attach anything to your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkMeyer pointed out, `currentNode = Node(data)` only creates a local variable. Therefore you need to return curretNode variable to the caller and update the node by returned variable.

When you fix four lines (#1 to #4), you will get the desired result.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            for elem in nodes:
                self.head = self.insert(self.head, elem) #1 Update the head
        print(self.head) #prints out None every time
        print(self.head.left)
        print(self.head.right)
        print(self.head.right.left)

    def insert(self, currentNode, data):
        if(currentNode == None):
            currentNode = Node(data)
        if(data != currentNode.data):
            if(data < currentNode.data): 
                if(currentNode.left is None): currentNode.left = Node(data)
                else: currentNode.left = self.insert(currentNode.left, data) #2 Update the left node
            elif(data > currentNode.data): 
                if(currentNode.right is None): currentNode.right = Node(data)
                else: currentNode.right = self.insert(currentNode.right, data) #3 Update the right node
        return currentNode #4 Return the currentNode
```

Here is the result.

```
1  # head
0  # head.left
80 # head.right
3  # head.right.left
```